# Looking for a way to re-subscribe to UnhandledException event

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have this third-party app that I am inheriting from that keeps stealing my subscription to the UnhandledException event (and suppressing all exceptions) and I am thinking about how I can tell whether the UnhandledExceptionEvent was stolen from me or not (since it only allows 1 subscriber). The third-party app keeps doing it at different periods so I am thinking of fighting back with a timer and stealing the third-party's subscription to the UnhandledException event. The problem with the third-party app is that I have no control over it. Any better ideas?

Comment: Using a timer would introduce a race-condition.

Comment: yup, but I might be able to get exceptions sometimes... :-)

Comment: Which exception handler? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException? When I subsribe two times to it I get both notifications but after the last handler is executed the application is terminated. Does the third party app perhaps never return from its handler?

Comment: You are dealing with a programmer that doesn't trust you to get it right.  Bit of a problem with most programmers, being God is pretty easy in software, unlike the Real World.  You'll have to get God on the phone.  Don't expect Him to call back, the odds He'll respond to your question are zilch.